# How to use Firefox's headers on PhantomJS in Selenium?

Tags: python, python-2.7, firefox, selenium, phantomjs

Besides setting each header manually, is there a way to copy all of Firefox's headers and set them on PhantomJS?

Manual way:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ("Mozilla/5.0")
```

There must be an easy way to get all the headers from Firefox. Any ideas?

Thanks so much! :)